# vim find out what is changing the directory

Tags: vim

I usually start vim from the folder where I have my Makefile and tags file
and edit a file that is two levels down the three.
So if I am at folder x I usually would do vim x1/x2/code.c
The problem is that recently vim changes the folder to the folder where the code is (so if I do pwd it will show x1/x2).
I want it to stay at the top folder.

Is there a way of knowing what is causing the change of folder? I am assuming that is some kind of plugin but have not been able to track it down.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you initiate the edit of the file in the other folder?  I.e. do you use `:e x1/x2/code.c` or some other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have autochdir turned on in your vimrc. `:set autochdir?` to check.

There are any number of plugins that could be doing it, do you happen to remember what you've installed recently?

Comment: :set autochdir returns noautochdir.

Comment: The ones I think I installed more recently are Ack, fuzzyfinder, supertab and A.vim

Comment: Well... it's not A.vim (I have that installed here), but fuzzyfinder looks quite suspicious.

Comment: I believe it was fuzzyfinder, deleted the files from that plugin and since then haven't experienced the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is the request for the Benoit answer. (I am not sure if I should post it as an answer or edit the question).

```
 1: .vimrc
  2: temp/MyInstalls/linux/Packages/vim73/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: temp/MyInstalls/linux/Packages/vim73/share/vim/vim73/syntax/synload.vim
  4: temp/MyInstalls/linux/Packages/vim73/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: temp/MyInstalls/linux/Packages/vim73/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim
  6: temp/MyInstalls/linux/Packages/vim73/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin.vim
  7: temp/MyInstalls/linux/Packages/vim73/share/vim/vim73/indent.vim
  8: .vim/colors/graywh_cs.vim
  9: .vim/plugin/AlignMapsPlugin.vim
 10: .vim/plugin/AlignPlugin.vim
 11: .vim/plugin/ColorSchemes.vim
 12: .vim/plugin/NERD_commenter.vim
 13: .vim/plugin/NERD_tree.vim
 14: .vim/plugin/SyntaxFolds.vim
 15: .vim/plugin/a.vim
 16: .vim/plugin/ack.vim
 17: .vim/plugin/bufexplorer.vim
 18: .vim/plugin/buftabs.vim
 19: .vim/plugin/c.vim
 20: .vim/plugin/cecutil.vim
 21: .vim/plugin/changeColorScheme.vim
 22: .vim/plugin/conque_term.vim
 23: .vim/plugin/crefvim.vim
 24: .vim/plugin/cscope_maps.vim
 25: .vim/plugin/d/ColorSchemeMenuMaker.vim
 26: .vim/plugin/d/ColorSchemes.vim
 27: .vim/plugin/d/filebrowser.vim
 28: .vim/plugin/d/libList.vim
 29: .vim/plugin/echofunc.vim
 30: .vim/plugin/filebrowser.vim
 31: .vim/plugin/fuf.vim
 32: .vim/autoload/fuf/buffer.vim
 33: .vim/autoload/fuf.vim
 34: .vim/autoload/fuf/file.vim
 35: .vim/autoload/fuf/dir.vim
 36: .vim/autoload/fuf/bookmark.vim
 37: .vim/autoload/fuf/tag.vim
 38: .vim/autoload/fuf/taggedfile.vim
 39: .vim/autoload/fuf/jumplist.vim
 40: .vim/autoload/fuf/changelist.vim
 41: .vim/autoload/fuf/quickfix.vim
 42: .vim/autoload/fuf/line.vim
 43: .vim/autoload/fuf/help.vim
 44: .vim/autoload/fuf/givenfile.vim
 45: .vim/autoload/fuf/givendir.vim
 46: .vim/autoload/fuf/givencmd.vim
 47: .vim/autoload/fuf/callbackfile.vim
 48: .vim/autoload/fuf/callbackitem.vim
 49: .vim/plugin/imaps.vim
 50: .vim/plugin/libList.vim
 51: .vim/plugin/lightWeightArray.vim
 52: .vim/plugin/matchit.vim
 53: .vim/plugin/mru.vim
 54: .vim/plugin/outlinetoggle.vim
 55: .vim/plugin/remoteOpen.vim
 56: .vim/plugin/scratch.vim
 57: .vim/plugin/snipMate.vim
 58: .vim/plugin/srcexpl.vim
 59: .vim/plugin/supertab.vim
 60: .vim/plugin/swap_parameters.vim
 61: .vim/plugin/taglist.vim
 62: .vim/plugin/timestamp.vim
 63: .vim/plugin/totd.vim
 64: .vim/plugin/ttcplug.vim
 65: temp/MyInstalls/linux/Packages/vim73/share/vim/vim73/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 66: temp/MyInstalls/linux/Packages/vim73/share/vim/vim73/plugin/gzip.vim
 67: temp/MyInstalls/linux/Packages/vim73/share/vim/vim73/plugin/matchparen.vim
 68: temp/MyInstalls/linux/Packages/vim73/share/vim/vim73/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 69: temp/MyInstalls/linux/Packages/vim73/share/vim/vim73/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 70: temp/MyInstalls/linux/Packages/vim73/share/vim/vim73/plugin/spellfile.vim
 71: temp/MyInstalls/linux/Packages/vim73/share/vim/vim73/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 72: temp/MyInstalls/linux/Packages/vim73/share/vim/vim73/plugin/tohtml.vim
 73: temp/MyInstalls/linux/Packages/vim73/share/vim/vim73/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 74: temp/MyInstalls/linux/Packages/vim73/share/vim/vim73/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 75: .vim/after/plugin/snipMate.vim
 76: .vim/nerdtree_plugin/exec_menuitem.vim
 77: .vim/nerdtree_plugin/fs_menu.vim
 78: temp/MyInstalls/linux/Packages/vim73/share/vim/vim73/scripts.vim
```